# Inequality proof.

Tags: inequality

How can I prove, the following:

For all $x,y,t,s$

$$(8tx+ty+sx+6sy)^2\leq(8t^2+2ts+6s^2)(8x^2+2xy+6y^2)$$

I think, that Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is required here.

Comment: At the very end, you have $2y$. It can't be $2y$. You need another variable.

Comment: You are right!!!!!!!!

Comment: Symmetry suggests that either $2x$ should be $2xy$, or $2ts$ should be $2t$.

Comment: You have an error. Try $t=y=0, x=-\frac14$ for e.g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce the inner product $ \langle . \rangle : \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ as $ \langle (x,y),(t,s)\rangle = 8tx+ty+sx+6sy $, then this is just Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. You have a typo though in the RHS as pointed out above, $2xy$ in place of $2x$.

Answer (score 0):

By C-S we obtain:
$$(8t^2+2ts+6s^2)(8x^2+2xy+6y^2)=\left(2\left(2t+\frac{s}{4}\right)^2+\frac{47s^2}{8}\right)\left(2\left(2x+\frac{y}{4}\right)^2+\frac{47y^2}{8}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\left(2\left(2t+\frac{s}{4}\right)\left(2x+\frac{y}{4}\right)+\frac{47sy}{7}\right)^2=(8tx+ty+sx+8sy)^2.$$
Done!